# Shimano Nexus SG C6000-8R and SL-S503

Tags: shimano, internally-geared-hub, compatibility, nexus

I have a very specific compatibility issue : I just bought a Shimano Nexus 8 "SG C6000-8R" rear hub and would like to know if I can use it with the Shimano "SL-S503" gear trigger.

The [reference page](http://bike.shimano.com/content/sac-bike/en/home/components11/city---comfort/nexus1/sg-8c31.html), **which is about a slightly different hub** (mine doesn't have coaster brake) claims that we can use it with the Shimano SL-50**0**, nothing said about SL-50**3**.

So, does anyone have experience having a bike with both components? Or can someone surely say that they will work together.

More generally though, I don't understand how references are made: what's the difference between the SL-S500 and SL-S503, between the SG C6000 and SG C6001, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer depends heavily on Shimano documentation and has a number of links to the Shimano website, which will inevitably suffer from rot. My apologies to all those reading this years from now when Shimano has changed all the URLs.

---

I *think* that in general the last couple of digits in Shimano component names/codes denote variations in the spec or quality level of the components.

One can dig around in Shimano's tech documents looking for answers. Current URL is http://si.shimano.com/#/

The [Line Up Chart](http://productinfo.shimano.com/#/lc/2.2) offers some insight into the compatibility of current parts (note there is an archive also).

The [Nexus Inter 8 Chart](http://productinfo.shimano.com/#/lc/2.2/nexus/inter-8) indicates that the SG-C6001-8R hub can be used with the SL-S503 lever.

I note that the the *8R* postfix in the hub name denotes 'roller brake spec', but I'm not sure if that means it has a roller brake built in or it is compatible with a roller brake. There seems to be a specific compatibility with brake levers for roller brakes.

Update: after reading the Sheldon Brown / Harris Cyclery page on roller brakes, I found out that the 'R' postfix hubs are compatible with an add on brake unit.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I guess the "R" means that it is compatible with a roller brake, not built-in. (Thanks for editing btw)